# onlocationChange is not calling

Tags: android, location

I have tried some other same questions too but I don't know where I am wrong. On location change is not called even when app starts. I tried it by moving the device too. here is my code -

```
public class DriverMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    Location location;
    LocationRequest mLocatioRequest;
    LocationCallback locationCallback;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver_map);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        this.locationCallback = (new LocationCallback() {
            public void onLocationResult(@Nullable LocationResult locationResult) {
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).
        addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).
                addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

        String userid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        Log.d("checkingLocId",userid+"Funtion called");
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("driversAvailable");
        GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
        geoFire.setLocation(userid, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mLocatioRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocatioRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocatioRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocatioRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocatioRequest, this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

        String userid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("driverAvailable");
        GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
        geoFire.removeLocation(userid);

    }
}
```

Comment: Check if this line is executed or not : LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocatioRequest, this);

Comment: @RajatMehra this is executing ..

Answer (score 0):

Change your requestLocationUpdates method call.

Replace

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocatioRequest, this);
```

With

```
LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this).requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
            new LocationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                    // your code
                }
            },
            null);
```

Comment: then what about GoogleAPIClient ?

Comment: getting error where passing this in the requestLocationUpdate(mLocatioRequest, this -> getting error here, null)